# Access Google Contacts API on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm struggling to access the Google Contacts API.

First I tried the `google-api-ruby-client` gem but it turned out that it [does not support the Contacts API](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/136).

Next shot was the `google_contacts_api` [gem](https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api) but I struggle to get a `oauth_access_token_for_user` with the `oAuth2` [gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2). When following the [oAuth2 instructions](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2#usage-examples) I don't know what to put in `authorization_code_value` and `Basic some_password`.

I tried the following:

```
require 'oauth2'
client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], :site => 'http://localhost:9292')
=> #<OAuth2::Client:0x007fcf88938758 @id="blabla.apps.googleusercontent.com", @secret="blabla", @site="http://localhost:9292", @options={:authorize_url=>"/oauth/authorize", :token_url=>"/oauth/token", :token_method=>:post, :connection_opts=>{}, :connection_build=>nil, :max_redirects=>5, :raise_errors=>true}>

client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:9292')
=> "http://localhost:9292/oauth/authorize?client_id=blabla.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9292&response_type=code"

token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:9292', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic some_password'})
=> Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9292
```

I would appreciate if someone could give me detailed step by step instructions how to access the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your app is set up properly and that you've enabled the Contacts API in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). Then try this:

```
CLIENT_ID = '?????.apps.googleusercontent.com'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_secret'
REDIRECT_URI = 'your_redirect_uri'
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, 
           site: 'https://accounts.google.com',
           token_url: '/o/oauth2/token',
           authorize_url: '/o/oauth2/auth')
url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(scope: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
           redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI)
```

Visit `url` in your browser and log in to Google. The url you are redirected to afterwards will contain the token in the parameter `code`. It will look like this (this next line is not code you run):

```
actual_redirect_url = "#{REDIRECT_URI}?code=#{code}"
```

Parse the code from the redirect url, then

```
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
```

*Edit*

Someone asked in the comments how to pass the token to the google_contacts_api library. (I wrote the library, so I should know!)

`token` is an `OAuth2::AccessToken` object in this example. All you have to do is pass it to the constructor:

```
user = GoogleContactsApi::User.new(token)
```

To be extra clear, the constructor accepts the token object, not a string.

Comment: Thanks alot alvin, but I am getting stuck. I am able to get the access token whick is in this format: #<OAuth2::AccessToken:0x000000037a69d34>. But now how am I going to continue with the google_contacts_api gem. How should I pass the token to it. I would appreciate if you could give something a bit detailed?

Comment: All you have to do is pass the token to the constructor: `GoogleContactsApi::User.new(token)`

Comment: Your answer helped me authorize and even get the token. When I pass the token to the constructor as you have suggested it is giving an error. I have posted a question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052480/how-to-access-google-contacts-api-in-ruby. Plz have a look at the question

Comment: What I want to do is, I want to access all the email addresses in my Gmail contacts. You can also suggest a way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're authenticating against localhost (should only be referring to localhost in the context of redirecting after authentication). You should be authenticating against Google's OAuth server somewhere in there.

See: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/google/api_client.rb#L165